# Does python have a better way to split a string than converting to a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am testing a set of web apis, using python, a language I am still in the process of learning.  I am taking in a string, the name of a dealer, and chopping off the end after a random number of characters.  I am then adding a character (wild card) to then end of the string.  That modified string is then passed to an api that searches for the name of a dealer, and can include wild cards.  I have the code below, but it seems long.  Is there a cleaner looking, or  more pythonic way of approaching this problem?  Potentially a way to do this without converting from a string, to a list, back to a string?

```
split_name = list(name)     #turns name string into list
rand = random.randint(6,(len(split_name)-1))    #generates random number
split_name[rand:len(split_name)] = []       #breaks of end part of name list
srch_name = ''.join(split_name)     #stringifies list
#Send request
rqst = requests.get(name_srch %(key, (srch_name + '*'))) #this adds * and sends the request
```

Name is earlier defined in the script to be some string, such as "Dave and Bills equipment sales and service, INC"
I should note I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use slicing to pick a random number of characters from the string, no need to split it into a list first:

```
rand = random.randint(6, len(split_name) - 1)
search_name = name[rand:] + '*'
rqst = requests.get(name_srch % (key, search_name))
```

Strings are sequences too and support slicing *directly* without needing to turn it into a list first. You can omit the end-point, slicing defaults to the end of the string in that case.

Comment: In response to your original answer: it should be noted that `string.split()` is around twice as fast as `list(string)`.

Comment: @2rs2ts: but the `.split()` does something *completely different*.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, this is a better solution. At some point I have to search for partialword*partialword. With the method you have shown that becomes much easier than my code (i won't paste here, it looks terrible), as its just 
    'search_name = name[:rand1] + "*" + name[rand2:]'
with the rands appropriately calculated.

@2rs2ts, I had thought about using 'string.split()' but didn't see a need to only insert the wildcard between whole words.  Out of curiosity, why would it be about twice as fast?  Just because it's creating a smaller list?